# Feature Extraction using MFCC

Tags: python-3.x, mfcc

I want to know, how to extract the audio (x.wav) signal, feature extraction using MFCC? I know the steps of the audio feature extraction using MFCC. I want to know the fine coding in Python using the Django framework

Comment: I am doing research on voice recognition using MFCC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most important step in building a speech recognizer because after converting the speech signal into the frequency domain, we must convert it into the usable form of the feature vector.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.io import wavfile
from python_speech_features import mfcc, logfbank

frequency_sampling, audio_signal = 
wavfile.read("/home/user/Downloads/OSR_us_000_0010_8k.wav")

audio_signal = audio_signal[:15000]

features_mfcc = mfcc(audio_signal, frequency_sampling)

print('\nMFCC:\nNumber of windows =', features_mfcc.shape[0])
print('Length of each feature =', features_mfcc.shape[1])



features_mfcc = features_mfcc.T
plt.matshow(features_mfcc)
plt.title('MFCC')

filterbank_features = logfbank(audio_signal, frequency_sampling)

print('\nFilter bank:\nNumber of windows =', filterbank_features.shape[0])
print('Length of each feature =', filterbank_features.shape[1])

filterbank_features = filterbank_features.T
plt.matshow(filterbank_features)
plt.title('Filter bank')
plt.show()
```

or you may use this code to extract the feature

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
import python_speech_features as mfcc

def extract_features(audio,rate):
"""extract 20 dim mfcc features from an audio, performs CMS and combines 
delta to make it 40 dim feature vector"""    

        mfcc_feature = mfcc.mfcc(audio,rate, 0.025, 0.01,20,nfft = 1200, appendEnergy = True)    
        mfcc_feature = preprocessing.scale(mfcc_feature)
        delta = calculate_delta(mfcc_feature)
        combined = np.hstack((mfcc_feature,delta)) 
        return combined
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use following code to extract an audio file MFCC features using librosa package(it is easy to install and work):

```
import librosa
import librosa.display
audio_path = 'my_audio_file.wav'
x, sr = librosa.load(audio_path)
mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(x, sr=sr,n_mfcc=40)
print(mfccs.shape)
```

also you can Display  the MFCCs using following code:

```
librosa.display.specshow(mfccs, sr=sr, x_axis='time')
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged on SO, & less likely to be upvoted over time. Consider editing to add an explanation or links to documentation. Also, it's recommended to remove the word "simply" from answers.